# How do I create a linkedList with a certain size?

Tags: java, list

I have to allow the user to input int elements, which will be inserted in the created linkedList either at the beginning or end, or certain position.

```
   linkedList list = new linkedList();
```

To instert elements, I'm using this code:

```
   public void insert(int val){
        Node nptr = new Node(val, null, null);
        Node tmp, ptr;        
        boolean ins = false;
        if (start == null){            
            nptr.setLinkNext(nptr);
            nptr.setLinkPrev(nptr);
            start = nptr;
            end = start;            
        }
        else if (val <= start.getData()){
            nptr.setLinkPrev(end);
            end.setLinkNext(nptr);
            start.setLinkPrev(nptr);
            nptr.setLinkNext(start);
            start = nptr;
        }
        else if (val >= end.getData()){
            end.setLinkNext(nptr);
            nptr.setLinkPrev(end);
            nptr.setLinkNext(start);
            start.setLinkPrev(nptr);
            end = nptr;
        }
        else{
            tmp = start;
            ptr = start.getLinkNext();
            while (ptr != null){
                if (val >= tmp.getData() && val <= ptr.getData()){
                    tmp.setLinkNext(nptr);
                    nptr.setLinkPrev(tmp);
                    nptr.setLinkNext(ptr);
                    ptr.setLinkPrev(nptr);
                    ins = true;
                    break;
                }
                else{
                    tmp = ptr;
                    ptr = ptr.getLinkNext();
                }
            }
            if (!ins){
                tmp.setLinkNext(nptr);
                nptr.setLinkPrev(tmp);
            }
        }
        size++;
    }
```

What I need is to allow doing this only until the max size of list reaches 10 elements. How do I accomplish that?

Also, I am using switch and cases for this. This is not the complete code, just parts of it, because the code is huge.

```
            case 1 : 
                System.out.println("Enter integer element to insert");
                list.insert( scan.nextInt() );                     
                break;
```

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a place to ask people to do your homework for you

Comment: I wouldn't ask, if I could find the answer myself...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you could use :

```
list.size()
```

To get the number of elements in the linked list and accordingly add.

If this is not feasible then you could write your own linked list that would not take more than predefined number of elements.

Or you could simply have a class that holds a linked list .And you handle all events pertaining that linked list in that class. You would have to access it through a object though.

This topic is quiet broad . There are many ways ,do some research and do what suits yu best .

Answer (score 0):

It would be much easier in your case to check the size of LinkedList before insertion:

```
if(list.size()>=10){//Do something...}
```

Otherwise, there is no specified maximum size of LinkedList structure.

Comment: He is talking about **raw linkedlist** and obviously he will have to keep track of **when** and **how** the list's **size expanded** inside the **insert(int)** method. Doesn't answer it truly though

Comment: Well, in such a case it would be fine just to add a simple counter.

Comment: Yep, and you will have to make those **simple counter edits** if you wish to get your answer accepted :) that's all im trying to help you with, **how to get your answer accepted as right** :)

Comment: Thanks :) Was just referring to "This is not the complete code, just parts of it, because the code is huge."

Comment: OMG actually you are exactly right with that **This is not the complete code, just parts of it, because the code is huge** :D but still you are going to have to make those edits before you start getting huge downvotes for your answer :)